# Detect Error with SimpleXMLElement?

Tags: php, simplexml

I want to be able to detect error with SimpleXMLElement, the errors being:

```
failed to open HTTP stream
failed to load external entity
Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML'
```

I have the following code to attempt to detect error.

```
$xml =  new SimpleXMLElement("https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom",null,true);
if ($xml === FALSE) {
echo "Wrong username/password combination.";
}
```

This doesn't work.... how do I make error detection work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exceptions can be caught using a try catch construction:

```
try {
     $oXml 
}
catch(Excepton $oException) {
   // Something went wrong!
}
```

For the HTTP / Load problems I suggest you use a combination of:

1. [CURL](http://nl.php.net/curl) to check valid response
2. [simplexml_load_string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php).parse the response, and catch any warnings using [libxml_use_internal_errors](http://php.net/libxml_use_internal_errors%28%29)